# TweenJS multiple tweens on multiple targets

Tags: javascript, createjs, tweenjs

I am using Tweenjs and have the following issue;

I have set up a createJS “container”  which has a graphic inside of it called “myimage”

The idea is to tween myimage inside the container to a new x and y position. This should be followed by rotating the container through an angle.

Currently I have two functions as follows;

```
function moveMyimage(){


Createjs.Tween.get(myimage)
                .to({x: 100, y: 200}, 1500, createjs.Ease.quadInOut)
                .wait(1000)

}
```

And

```
Function rotateContainer(){

Createjs.Tween.get(container)
              .to({rotation: 180}, 2500, createjs.EasequadInOut)


}
```

Currently each function (for test purposes) is linked to a separate button which may be used to fire them. On their own they work fine.

However if I try to combine them inside a single function

```
function moveMyimage(){


Createjs.Tween.get(myimage)
                .to({x: 100, y: 200}, 1500, createjs.Ease.quadInOut)
                .wait(1000)

Createjs.Tween.get(container)
              .to({rotation: 180}, 2500, createjs.EasequadInOut)


}
```

I find that `myimage` moves fine inside the container but then instead of the rotate being applied to the container it is applied to the `myimage` inside the container.

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry I don't have a jsfiddle.

Comment: Observation: The Ease parameter on the rotation tween is missing a dot (`createjs.Ease.quadInOut`). It is correct on the movement tween.